# React without webpack project setup

Tags: reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I am learning React. I wanted to create new project using React/React router/ES6. I read tones articles about setuping project using grunt/webpack etc. I tried to setup using simply npm. I believe it is possible to do this without of tons of configuration and adding many external libraries. But I don't know how :) Can someone give me some articles how to setup project using only npm?

Thanks for all answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best easy way to start  react project

install react-create app by using following command

//install react create app globally to the system

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

// generate project

```
create-react-app appName
cd my-app/
npm start
```

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot. Do you recommend this on production enviroment or it is only good for practising in development?

Comment: It is good for development, For production you have need more config setup like, redux, saga etc